# Finding the distance from source in triple slit interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, waves, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I was wondering about the nature of the 3 slit interference pattern, as shown in fig 1. The line labelled L<sub>T</sub>/2, matches with fig 2 and all other diagrams I have seen depicting the same thing. I was wondering about the line labelled L<sub>T</sub>/4, what are the conditions for this alternative pattern, given a set source wavelength, the slit widths and distance between them?

### Fig 1:

[image]

### Fig 2:

[image]

Comment: The pattern resembles what one would see under the Talbot effect. Here, we get a divergent pattern, probably because the experiment only involves three slits. So I think what you have here is something between the two slit interference and the Talbot effect.